# iPhone: How do you get the names of all the address books on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook, exchange-server

Some users have multiple address books in their iPhone Contacts, as a result of different synchronization connections they have made with e.g. Exchange Servers.

How is it possible to get all of these different address books? I would be interested in getting the names under which these different address books are saved and accessing their contact information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef sourcesArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook);
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(sourcesArray); i++) {
    ABRecordRef source = (ABRecordRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sourcesArray, i);
    ABRecordID sourceID = ABRecordGetRecordID(source);
    CFNumberRef sourceType = (CFNumberRef)ABRecordCopyValue(source, kABSourceTypeProperty);
    CFStringRef sourceName = (CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(source, kABSourceNameProperty);
    NSLog(@"source id=%d type=%d name=%@", sourceID, [(NSNumber *)sourceType intValue], sourceName);
    CFRelease(sourceType);
    if (sourceName != NULL) CFRelease(sourceName); // some source names are NULL
}
CFRelease(sourcesArray);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Note that, as of iOS 4, not all sources return a name. You may provide your own names based on type.

Use `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource(addressBook, source)` to get entries in a source.

Comment: I got crash on CFRelease(sourceType) - with ARC.

Comment: ABAddressBookCreate() is deprecated use ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL) instead

Answer (score -1):

There is only a single, centralized address book database on iOS accessible by a set of C functions, see [ABAddressBook](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007099) and the [iOS address book programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744).

You may be referring to groups within that address book. In that case, you can get the list of groups using the `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups` function as described in the [reference on `ABGroup`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABGroupRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007211).

Comment: Apple documentation at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html : The listing below "The following code listing shows an example of sorting the entire Address Book database:" uses `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` to access the entire database. The method `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource` is a more restricted version, see the `ABPerson` documentation at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html